# Jenkins inside a Docker container

Tags: jenkins, docker, integration

Why is there a lot of resources (and recommendations) to run Jenkins inside a Docker container?

Am I correct if I think it is because the Docker container represents the production environment? The Continuous integration is there inside the container to pull changes from the repository and run the tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running CI in dockerized environment has many advantages:

- Creating identical Development/Production Environment will help you with Development and Tests.
- Rapid Launching and reseting development environment increases the agility of development.
- Ability to automate builds and tests in Identical Developement/Production Environment will result in more sophisticated testing as well as faster testing phase.

> Am I correct if I think it is because the Docker container represents the production environment?

yes,You can Configure your dockerized environment to reperesent exact production environment.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and short, but straightforward answer. I always thought you run Jenkins and Jenkins will create a container to run the integration proces.

Comment: Jenkins has a plugin for docker, And jenkins can run tests in a container. so you are correct, But you create the image that jenkins will do the build inside.

Comment: That is where my confusion came from I assume. I do not need an image tho after integration is done. Meaning the first answer suits my needs, but I understand the other way around now aswell.

Comment: Consider reading https://blog.philipphauer.de/tutorial-continuous-delivery-with-docker-jenkins/ , its a bit outdated by will explain continous integration and delivery in detail.